# Masonry: Layout isn't triggered when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

[Here is the site.](http://keebs.com/sandbox)

When I resize my window, the layout isn't triggered. So after I resize, I have to refresh the browser in order to see the reconfigured layout. I looked through the Masonry docs and found this page which I think describes my problem: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#bindresize

`$container.masonry('bindResize')`

However, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to implement it. Below is the code that I'm currently using.

```
if(jQuery().isotope) {

    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1035 ? 240 : 320
            },
            getSortData: {

                order: function($elem) {
                    return parseInt($elem.attr('data-order'));
                }

            },
            sortBy: 'order'
        }, function() {

            // Isotope Chrome Fix   
            setTimeout(function () {        
                jQuery('#masonry').isotope('reLayout'); 
            }, 1000);

        });


    }); 

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){

        jQuery('#filter li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-filter');

        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;

    });


}
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jQuery().isotope) {

    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 240
            },
            getSortData: {

                order: function($elem) {
                    return parseInt($elem.attr('data-order'));
                }

            },
            sortBy: 'order'
        }, function() {

            // Isotope Chrome Fix   
            setTimeout(function () {        
                jQuery('#masonry').isotope('reLayout'); 
            }, 1000);

        });


    }); 

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){

        jQuery('#filter li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-filter');

        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;

    });
//added this line
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){jQuery('#masonry').isotope('reLayout'); });
}
```

I have just added a single line in last and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post because the `columnWidth` was wrong. It's actually `columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1035 ? 240 : 320`. Does your answer change because of that?

Comment: I just put in that line, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to insert the bindResize Snippet after your $container var?

```
    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    $container.masonry('bindResize');

    jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){ 
     ...
    }
```

The bindResize method should triggered on the Resize-Event so you don’t need to add it to the event manually. But the Amit’s solution should work too. But can you please remove the refreshing on the demo-site on resize? i can’t really test anything there.

Comment: I just tried your solution but it didn't work. Unfortunately, Amit's solution didn't work as well. I put the original code back in. How do I remove the refreshing on the site?

Comment: @Desi just remove line 75 in your custom-js.js (wp-content/themes/adapt-child/js/)+

Comment: Line 75 is just a closing bracket. Do you want me to remove that line?

Comment: @Desi no you just removed the right line. But it works. The Layout are refreshed on resize. Do you still have the issue? When I resize my browser, the Masonry Layout is changing.

Comment: It only changes when you resize down from 1035px to 680px, but not from 100% to 1035px.

Comment: So you want a fullscreen/fullwidth masonry-grid?! Then you have to move the #masonry-Container after the <div id="main"> in your DOM. (just check your templates, maybe its easily possible with a template-setting)

Comment: No, not a full width grid. If you open the demo site in my post, you'll see the four columns (3 columns of blogs + sidebar). When I resize the browser down, I want the blogs to reduce to 2 columns. But it only shows the 2 columns when I refresh, not automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50013/discussion-between-patrick-ludewig-and-desi)